# How to summarize the index of odd numbers in haskell?

Tags: haskell

Amount of items with odd number 
Define the function f4, which represents the sum of elements of a unique index in a list! Indexing is exceptional!

```
f4 :: [Int] -> Int
f4 [] == 0
f4 [4] == 4
f4 [4.2] == 4
f4 [4,2,3] == 7
f4 [4,2,3,5] == 7
f4 [5,4,2,3,8,3,9,5,2] == 26

f4 :: [Int] -> Int
f4 [] = 0
f4 [x] = x
f4 (x:xs) = odd (x:xs)
```

Comment: I don't understand anything in this question. Please edit it and try to explain your problem better.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I understood of the console output, this function can help you:

```
sumOdds :: [Double] -> Int
sumOdds []  = 0
sumOdds [a] = round a
sumOdds (x:xs) = round x + sumOdds (tail xs)
```